# TSOA @UploadedFile won't accept file

Tags: typescript, postman, tsoa

I have an endpoint defined to accept a `multipart/form-data` file like so:

```
@Post('/...')
@SuccessResponse(202, 'Accepted')
@Response(400, 'Bad request')
@Response(404, 'Not found')
public async acceptFile(
    @UploadedFile('file') file: Express.Multer.File
): Promise<...> {
    return this.fileService.acceptFile(file);
}
```

When I send a `multipart/form-data` request with a file parameter, TSOA does not accept this request, claiming that "'file' is required". Even though I provided it:

[image]

As you can see the request is created by Postman, is correct and has the `file` form data parameter. According to [TSOA file upload documentation](https://tsoa-community.github.io/docs/file-upload.html#using-the-uploadedfile-uploadedfiles-decorator) this should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to solve this and so implemented a workaround:

First added multer middleware to handle form-data files:

```
const multerAny = multer({
      storage: multer.diskStorage()
    }).any();
app.use(multerAny);
```

Then I used raw express request that TSOA can also inject and got the file from that:

```
@Post('/...')
@SuccessResponse(202, 'Accepted')
@Response(400, 'Bad request')
@Response(404, 'Not found')
public async acceptFile(
    @Request() request: Express.Request
): Promise<...> {
    //request.files will have file array, check if it has elements
    return this.fileService.acceptFile(request.files[0]);
}
```